# Custom Read More in React.js

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

[image]

As you can see this image, "+Las mor" is a "see more" button, which when clicked expands the whole paragraph written above.
I need React code for this to be functional. Any help will be appreciated.
I am also attaching the code upon which this functionality is to be applied.

```
<section id="section-2">
 <h4>Om mig</h4>
 <p className="para">
  {about} 
 </p>
</section>
<p style={{color:'#d39176'}}>
 <img src={plus1} />
 Läs mer
</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably want a button that toggles the state of expanded text onClick. Upon hitting the button you would set the state to the opposite of what it was. Here's a working example I wrote with React and Reactstrap. I just tested it locally. Here's a video demo of what you will see: https://screencast.com/t/in5clDiyEcUs

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Container, Button } from 'reactstrap'

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      expanded: false //begin with box closed
    }
  }

  //function that takes in expanded and makes it the opposite of what it currently is
  showButton = () => { 
    this.setState({ expanded: !this.state.expanded })
  }

  render() {
    const { expanded } = this.state
    return (
      <Container style={ { justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' } }>
        <div>Always visable text.</div>
        <Button onClick={ this.showButton }>Expand</Button>
        { 
          expanded && //show if expanded is true
          <div>Extended Text Here</div>
        }
      </Container>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

Comment: I just updated it to be a working example. There is also a video of it working now.

Comment: This is a good answer. What she's basically saying is that you need to have a `bool` in your state which switches to the opposite value when the "see more" button is clicked. In your JSX, you should display your extra text using `<div>` (or whatever) and use the bool in your state to control its visibility.